# how to stop or jump signal and go to main?

Tags: c, linux, signals

What should i add to code to stop the signal and return to Main?

Do not use '() exit',  i want to end or jump signal and go to main fuction.
i try to branch. but it's not works.

---

```
main{

  void countdown(int); 
  signal (SIGALRM, countdown);
    .... 
    ....
    ....
}

void countdown(int signum)
{
    static int num =10;
    printf("%d..",num--);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (num <0){
        printf("DONE");
        exit(0); // i want to change do not use exit() and get out this signal
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you set the alarm `alarm()`. Also _get out this signal ?_ you meant for this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot invoke any of the functions you use from a signal handler. Only functions from [`man signal-safety` list](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

For the purpose of displaying progress indicator instead of using `alarm/SIGALRM` you may like start another thread that uses `nanosleep` to wait till the next tick and then print progress status.

Answer (score 0):

`signal` invokes asynchronously a function when a call is received. When the called function (`countdown` here) terminates, it return right in the place left when the signal was caught.

So here, I'll say you just have to remove `exit(0);` and let the nature do the rest.